# tsclean is affecting one value in the ts object

Tags: r, forecasting

When using the "tsclean" function on a ts (timeseries) object - only one of the value (2013-Dec) is getting affected as a whole. Not sure why.

As you can see "2013-Dec" value changed from 29232 to 51654.24. Rest are untouched.

```
> myts
       Jan   Feb   Mar   Apr   May   Jun   Jul   Aug   Sep   Oct   Nov   Dec
2013       44568 48528 46404 47772 57600 46116 20016 36504 47052 50076 29232
2014 52956 40284 51264 45180 42552 54972 47376 25128 34776 44892 44280 41076
2015 45036 50796 49572 39710 41045 62729 44424 18000 41642 42661 38487 51590
2016 38702 44803 58228 47556 48492 56449 34925 16812 48630 46008 40140 62028
> ifelse(tsclean(myts)<0, myts, tsclean(myts))
          Jan      Feb      Mar      Apr      May      Jun      Jul      Aug      Sep      Oct      Nov      Dec
2013          44568.00 48528.00 46404.00 47772.00 57600.00 46116.00 20016.00 36504.00 47052.00 50076.00 51654.24
2014 52956.00 40284.00 51264.00 45180.00 42552.00 54972.00 47376.00 25128.00 34776.00 44892.00 44280.00 41076.00
2015 45036.00 50796.00 49572.00 39710.00 41045.00 62729.00 44424.00 18000.00 41642.00 42661.00 38487.00 51590.00
2016 38702.00 44803.00 58228.00 47556.00 48492.00 56449.00 34925.00 16812.00 48630.00 46008.00 40140.00 62028.00
>
```

When I try the same value to pass as a subset to tsclean - it doesn't get affected.

```
> window(myts, c(2013,12), c(2013,12))
       Dec
2013 29232

> tsclean(window(myts, c(2013,12), c(2013,12)))
       Dec
2013 29232


> ifelse(tsclean(window(myts, c(2013,12), c(2013,12)))<0, window(myts, c(2013,12), c(2013,12)), tsclean(window(myts, c(2013,12), c(2013,12))))
       Dec
2013 29232
```

Answer (score 1):

tsclean function returns a seasonality adjusted timeseries, removing the seasonal component from the data if necessary. Take a look at the difference between the minimum and maximum for each month, the biggest differences is in December because of the December 2013 value that is abnormally low, this is why the function adjusted this part.
Here is the function that R used: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/forecast/versions/8.1/topics/seasadj